# 'missing routes' error handling in node.js express app (failing)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am simply trying to work within my `app.js` or router file to handle possible missing router errors. *(similar stackoverflow solutions have not worked for me)*

my `app.js` or router files is thus *(works fine as is; but am trying to handle missing router error properly)*:

```
'use strict'
var path = require('path');
var film = require('./healthymeals.js');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/allMeals', film.getAllMeals);

  app.get('/meals/:id', film.getMealInfo);

  app.get('/meals/:id/options',meal.getHealthyMealoptions);

  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Healthy meals");
  });
```

I have installed npm's/express error handling package '[**http-status-codes**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-status-codes)' .

And *tried* it's implementation:

```
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

response
    .status(HttpStatus.OK)
    .send('ok');

response
    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    .send({
        error: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    });
```

when the above is ran; I get a **build error** in terminal thrown on the '`response`' word. *I had no errors when installing relevant npm package.*

```
ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

I have *then* tried a few suggestions I found on stackover, *ie.*

```
function getAllApps(request, response) {
    appService.getApps(request.query.$expand).then(function (apps) {
        response.status(200).send(apps);
        })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred in Apps Api: ' + err);
      response.status(500).send("" + err);
    });
}
```

which is not effective and seems to just get ignored. any pointers appreciated *(first time using this stack)*. cheers

---

**Update,** with the answer below from Jonas w - I was first getting time out error as follows:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

And then after increasing time out, I am getting below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

---

For more context here is the test in which it is *not* passing with my attempts:

```
  describe('error handling', function() {
        it('handles missing routes', function(done) {
            request
                .get('/meals/brokenroute')
                .expect(404)
                .expect(function(res) {
                    ok('message' in res.body, '"message" key missing');
                })
                .end(done);
        });
```

Comment: I can't really figure out what you're asking. Requests for non-existent routes are handled using a 404, see the FAQ: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-404-responses. If you just want to send an error code see `sendStatus`: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus. As for your attempt to use `http-status-codes`, the `response` variable in their example refers to the `res` argument passed to your route handlers. I also suggest experimenting with Express generator to see how it does it.

Comment: Thanks for your input; I am attempting to solve this problem to pass mocha js test for missing route handling; I've include the test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution ive found yet ( using plain express only):

```
app.get('/allMeals', film.getAllMeals, END);

app.get('/meals/:id', film.getMealInfo, END);

 app.get('/meals/:id/options',meal.getHealthyMealoptions,END);

function END(req,res){
  res.end();
  //note that this wont call next...
}

//all errors are handled below

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
   res.status(404).end();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. so, i am completely replacing res.send.. with res.status..? I like it, but am getting 'Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded.'

Comment: Building on your logic; I added this and got my desired result '  res.status(404).send({
   message: 'Router not found.'
  });'